# Is reputation lost due to rep cap awarded in the same day

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

This is [the most complete answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/174490) I found on the about reputation.
You can read:

> Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days.

What about the same day ? 
Let's say that:

- I cap with a +30 Answer A
- A few minutes later I gain another  +30 for an Answer B (which is swallowed by the cap)
- My Answer A get's deleted
- I'm now under the cap again and have a 30 rep hole to reach the cap again.

Do I get the reputation that I should have got for Answer B since **I'm in the same day** ?

Comment: Yes. It's as if answer A never existed.

Comment: @Mysticial I know it is totally forgetten but then it means that my reputation was stored somewhere in case I go below the cap again ? Because Answer B was upvoted while I was *over* the limit.

Comment: When the auto-recalc kicks in, the numbers will clear themselves up. So any upvotes you got over the cap because of A will appear with +whatever rep.

Comment: @Mysticial Nice ! Thanks :) You can post this as an answer I don't think it can be more clear than that.

Comment: @Mysticial No, I cannot see any such behavior. I ran into the rep cap and had 30 rep annulled, then 20 rep was lost due to deletion. I never got the 20 back, not even after a recalc forced at `/reputation`.

Comment: @hexafraction Then that 20 rep came from a day that you didn't repcap. Note that they don't disappear from the day that the post is deleted. They disappear from the day that they were awarded. So if you got +20 yesterday and didn't cap. Then you capped today, and lost the 20, you still lose the 20.

Comment: @Mysticial No, it was [today](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1424875/hexafraction?tab=reputation) in GMT time which SE uses. It's marked "today" (yesterday now, everything is yesterday relative to today), and the cap was hit and the post deleted on the same day.

Comment: @hexafraction I can't see deleted posts on your reputation graph. Only you, mods, and devs can. Can you link post that got deleted?

Comment: @Mysticial I'm not allowed to do that. I can't get a URL for it. Wait, no. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508428/cant-do-simple-java-operation/17508433#17508433).

Comment: @hexafraction The post was made 2 days ago. Note that you didn't repcap two days ago. So assuming the two votes you got came on that first day, then your 2 votes were awarded on a day that you did not hit the repcap - hence it's lost when the post is deleted. (as if the post never existed)

Comment: @Mysticial Ah, got it. My bad.

Comment: @hexafraction Yeah, it's confusing. When Nick implemented the new rep system, he had to make a few design decisions on how to display the information. What you see on your reputation tab is how you reputation changed each day. But the way it is actually calculated underneath is slightly different. So visually it usually makes sense until you hit the repcap and these corner cases creep in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an answer gets deleted with < 3 and < 60 days, it's as if it never existed.

However, the UI in the rep-tab can be a bit weird when rep gets out of sync.
So in your case, over-the-cap votes you got on B will appear to give nothing even after A is deleted.

But the rep-recalc script will run within a few minutes after a deletion. That should re-sync your rep-tab.

---

Here's one of my days where I posted an answer that eventually got deleted.

[image]

I repcapped and got 6 accepts for a total `200 + 6*15 = 290` rep. But it shows +310 since this [deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7436401/922184) got 2 upvotes that day.

That extra +20 was deducted on Oct 31 '12 when I deleted the answer.

So it's a bit weird, but in the end, the numbers will turn out correct after a recalc.

Comment: Two totally different answers :(...

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd a few years ago the repcap worked differently