# What happens to the reputation you earn once you have reached the daily limit?

Tags: discussion, reputation

If you start a question that becomes popular on stack exchange, and then you reach the daily reputation cap, what happens to the extra reputation earned in that day?

Is it carried over, or lost forever?

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname I disagree on that duplicate.  Your question is specifically asking about the rep cap and dealing with deleted posts.  This one doesn't even cover that ground.  Deleted posts are a weird exception to the rep cap due to the way the system handles deleted posts.  I think there is a better duplicate out there.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170305/proposed-change-to-downvote-calculations-for-fairness-by-intent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't get that reputation, and you also won't get it next day. So yes, it is "lost forever".

Comment: Unless place is made for more reputation in the same day in that case you will earn it.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname huh? Meaning someone undoes their up-vote on a different question, then the next up-vote on the new question will get you +5 again (but net 0)? If you mean something else, could you be (a lot) more specific?

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname not really.  If I am rep capped and received 5 upvotes after hitting the cap, those votes are gone forever, even if I get 100 downvotes after that.  Once I am downvoted, then any **new** upvotes will count to get me back to the rep cap.

Comment: @psubsee2003 There is a recalc tool that will fix it : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184160/is-reputation-lost-due-to-rep-cap-awarded-in-the-same-day

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname the recalc is crediting you for deleted posts because deleted posts are treated like they never existed.  It is a weird scenario but you are never earning the rep you lost due to the cap, you are just getting the rep to get you back to the cap since the deleted post never existed.  Your original comment suggests that by getting downvotes will give you those votes back.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname regardless, the total rep you earned over 200 - after adjustments - is lost forever. It does not magically appear in subsequent days (the crux of the question here).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Guess I was the one misunderstanding it after all. Thanks for the clarification guys.